# Theory: How to tell major, minor, melodi, harmonic, natural apart

Tags: theory, piano

I'm currently learning theory and need some help. I can't necessarily tell apart Major and Minor scales (from the key signature and the scales) nor can I tell the harmonic form. I remember my teacher telling me that the major scales have no accidentals, and the minors and harmonic do, but I do not know how to tell if a scale is minor in natural or harmonic form.

Comment: Telling them apart when your **hear** them is much more important than when you **look** at them on paper, IMHO.

Comment: @alephzero This is theory, so it's all on paper. I will not have a piano during the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, from the key sig. Each and every major scale/key has a relative minor that uses the same notes, exactly. That's the *natural* minor. So, from the key sig. itself on the sheet, with 3#, it's either A major, or F# minor. Bb major or G minor has 2 bs. And so on.

From the sound of the scale, the third note is the defining one. It's either a major third or a minor third, slightly lower.

Let's now look at the *melodic* minor. Same first 5 notes as the harmonic and natural minor scales, but the notes 6 and 7 are the same as the *parallel* major. The *parallel* scales are those with the same letter names - C major/C minor; D major/ D minor, etc.

And now, the *harmonic* minor. That has the same notes as the natural with only the 7th note raised, to give a leading note just one semitone away from the root. That's done to sound more convincing than having a 7th scale degree like the one in the natural minor.

So, in summation - the *natural* minor has the same notes as the *relative* major. The *harmonic* minor has the same notes with just a sharpened 7th note - an accidental. The *melodic* minor has sharpened 6th and 7th notes, so two accidentals.

There are two melodic minors - jazzers use the same notes as the classical one (which I described) most of the time, whereas the classical melodic scale is as stated ascending, but it reverts to the natural minor notes descending. Confusing? I think so!

Comment: I agree it's very confusing but I also have another question what is a parallel scale? It's on my worksheet too.

Comment: Edited to explain.

Comment: Ooooh, @Tim, you did the thing that is a pet peeve of mine that I drill into my theory students not to do!  The 6th and 7th notes of harmonic and melodic minor scales are not *sharpened*. They are raised a half step!  Therefore, in flat minor scales, those notes will become natural. The accidentals that show up in minor are not necessarily sharps. You could have both be naturals. Or, as in the case of D minor, one natural and one sharp.

Comment: @HeatherS. - I find myself suitably chastised ! They are sharper than they were, but it's a good point raised (just like the notes!). I'll leave the text as is for now, but being a pedant myself, I'd say you're spot on! Thanks.